# how to create and add pictures with movement

Tags: discussion

[enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469774/go-back-to-the-last-command)
look at terdon answer How to create this kind of picture in ubuntu . Also I do not sure if ask this in here or there D:

Comment: You could have just added a comment under his post ;)

Comment: Here ya go: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast

Comment: Which, by the way, is exactly the reference I used to create that screencast :)

Comment: screencast... NICE. ...

Comment: Since this really isn't a meta question, closing it against this http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5622/are-animated-gifs-of-screencasts-welcome-at-ask-ubuntu